# Request with authorization and proxy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I want send request to server **with** authorization
and use proxy(**without** authorization)

I use apache httpcomponents

```
Request request =  Request.Post(getEndpoint())
            .body(new StringEntity(requestString))
            .connectTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT)
            .socketTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT)
            .viaProxy(new HttpHost(proxy));

byte[] response = Executor.newInstance()
            .auth(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password )
            .execute(post)
            .returnContent()
            .asBytes();
```

but request sending to server without proxy

I see executor has 
authPreemptive and authPreemptiveProxy methods

What is correct way send to server request